# import pymongo causes `ImportError: cannot import name BSON`. how do you fix the import error?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bson

I'm having trouble getting a simple Hello World app to work using Flask, MongoDB, and Python. The app is bombing when trying to import from the `bson` module. All modules were installed successfully via `pip` and I'm running in a `virtualenv`, so I'm not sure why I'm getting the error: `ImportError: cannot import name BSON`

Here is my sample app code:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask import g
from flask import jsonify
from flask import json
from flask import request
from flask import url_for
from flask import redirect
from flask import render_template
from flask import make_response
import pymongo
from pymongo import Connection
from bson import BSON
from bson import json_util

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():

    connection = Connection()
    # Get your DB
    db = connection.my_database
    # Get your collection
    cars = db.cars
    # Create some objects
    import datetime
    car = {"brand": "Ford",
           "model": "Mustang",
           "date": datetime.datetime.utcnow()}
    # Insert it
    cars.insert(car)
    json_docs = [json.dumps(doc, default=json_util.default) for doc in cars.find()]

    return json_docs


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 5000.
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

I'm not sure how to go about debugging this or if there's something I'm missing here.

Edit: results of `pip freeze`:

```
Flask==0.9
Jinja2==2.6
WTForms==1.0.2
Werkzeug==0.8.3
bson==0.3.3
distribute==0.6.28
mongo==0.2.0
pymongo==2.3
pytz==2012g
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Edit2: Removed bson and pymongo, reran `pip install pymongo`. Complete trace now:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
18:21:20 web.1  |   File ".../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1701, in __call__
18:21:20 web.1  |     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
18:21:20 web.1  |   File ".../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
18:21:20 web.1  |     response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
18:21:20 web.1  |   File ".../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
18:21:20 web.1  |     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
18:21:20 web.1  |   File ".../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1361, in full_dispatch_request
18:21:20 web.1  |     response = self.make_response(rv)
18:21:20 web.1  |   File ".../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1450, in make_response
18:21:20 web.1  |     rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
18:21:20 web.1  |   File ".../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 711, in force_type
18:21:20 web.1  |     response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
18:21:20 web.1  |   File ".../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 818, in run_wsgi_app
18:21:20 web.1  |     app_iter = app(environ, start_response)
18:21:20 web.1  | TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: There's something wrong with your _virtualenv_. Your example runs without any problems on a _virtualenv_ I've just created with _pymongo_ and _flask_. Which Python version are you using?

Comment: `Python 2.7.2 -- CUSTOM` according to `python --version`

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Try uninstalling the `bson` and `pymongo` packages and then reinstalling the `pymongo` package. `pymongo` installs its own `bson` package and I think you've overwritten it with the other `bson` package installation and that is probably what is causing your import error.

FYI:

- when you pip install pymongo it also installs bson but it does not ever print a message saying that it is install bson to your virtualenv site-packages
- also pymongo does not list bson as a dep
- also pip -v list does not show that bson is installed
- those bullet points IMO have some code smell (at least print a message stating you are installing bson)

Comment: Well it's now a different error: `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` in `...venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1701, in __call__

Comment: Can you post the complete traceback?

Comment: The other answer should solve your second problem. Anyway, the original problem is now solved.

Comment: can you share method how to proceed with respect to different environmen like linux or windows. @PedroRomano

Comment: Thanks, you just saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 33):

I met the same problem.
I think the reason is I install `pymongo` and then install `bson`.
Then I uninstall bson. Then I got this problem.

`pip freeze pymongo` it requires Nothing.

So maybe it has its own bson package.

What I solve this problem:

`pip uninstall pymongo`

`pip uninstall bson`

and then reinstall pymongo

`pip install pymongo`

Answer (score 7):

You are returning a list in `hello()`. You need to return a string or a Response object, see [Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#about-responses). E.g. convert the list to a string before returning:

```
return '\n'.join(json_docs)
```

Comment: That solved the final problem! Gave the original solution to Pedro and an upvote to you. Thanks Rob!