# ImportError: cannot import name _UNPACK_INT

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json
from bson import json_util
from bson.json_util import dum

app = Flask(__name__)


MONGODB_HOST = 'localhost'
MONGODB_PORT = 27017
DBS_NAME = 'donorschoose'
COLLECTION_NAME = 'projects'
FIELDS = {'school_state': True, 'resource_type': True, 'poverty_level': True, 'date_posted': True, 'total_donations': True, '_id': False}

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/donorschoose/projects")
def donorschoose_projects():
    connection = MongoClient(MONGODB_HOST, MONGODB_PORT)
    collection = connection[DBS_NAME][COLLECTION_NAME]
    projects = collection.find(projection=FIELDS)
    json_projects = []
    for project in projects:
        json_projects.append(project)
    json_projects = json.dumps(json_projects, default=json_util.default)
    connection.close()
    return json_projects


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000,debug=True)
```

This is the tutorial I am following: http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2015/01/interactive-data-visualization-d3-dc-python-mongodb/

Here is the error when I run the server.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "app.py", line 3, in
>   <module>
>       from pymongo import MongoClient   File "/home/olalkeith/Documents/Github/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/**init**.py",
>   line 83, in <module>
>       from pymongo.collection import ReturnDocument   File "/home/olalkeith/Documents/Github/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py",
>   line 27, in <module>
>       from bson.raw_bson import RawBSONDocument   File "/home/olalkeith/Documents/Github/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bson/raw_bson.py",
>   line 20, in <module>
>       from bson import _UNPACK_INT, _iterate_elements ImportError: cannot import name _UNPACK_INT

Comment: Do you have pymongo installed?

Comment: @wolendranh. Yes i do

Comment: This is what i get when i run pip freeze.bson==0.4.1
dum==0.4
Flask==0.10.1
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
pymongo==3.2
pytz==2015.7
six==1.10.0
Werkzeug==0.11.2
wheel==0.24.0

Comment: Is it in system python packages, or do you use virtualenvironment?

Comment: i use  virtualenvironment

Comment: Can you try to from pymongo import MongoClient in activated virtualenv in terminal

Comment: Do you happen to have a `bson.py` inside your project?

Comment: @wolendranh i run the server when I am in the virtualenv.

Comment: @dirn..No i don't have it.

Comment: have you tried removing your virtual environment and create a new environment?

Answer (score 20):

I just ran into same problem. Try removing the bson module and reinstalling pymongo. See this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12983651/4621508